# Print a list in lines of 8 (java)

Tags: java, list, loops

I need to print a list in lines of 8.  Say if the list was integers long it would print 8 on the first row and 2 on the next.  Here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    System.out.println(list[i] + " ");
}
```

How could I print it in lines of 8 instead of printing one per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder`:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.append(list[0]).append(" ");
 for (int i = 1 ; i < size; i++) {
      sb.append(list[i]).append(" ");
      if ( (i + 1) % 8 == 0 ) { sb.append("\n"); }
 }
 System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: This has a bug. It prints a newline after the first item.

Comment: Now you're printing 9 items on the first line.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it as well. Embarrassed.

Answer (score 2):

Every answer I've seen until now has a bug in where it breaks. Use the following:

```
int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};

int br = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    if (i % br == (br - 1))
        System.out.println();
}
```

Or:

```
int br = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i % br == 0)
        System.out.println();
    System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 
17 18
```

Here are some ways (taken from other answers to this question) that this **cannot** be done.

- Break when `i % 8 == 0`. This doesn't work because `0 % 8 == 0` is true, which means this will cause a break after the first element.
- Print the item first and then break when `i > 0 && (i % 8 == 0)`. This does not work because arrays are zero-indexed (e.g. `i` does not equal `8` until the 9th element. In other words, you'll have 9 items on the first line. However, this works if you check for the break before printing the element.
- Print out the first item and then start the loop index at `1`. This suffers from the same problem as the previous answer; you'll still always be one index behind.

You can use a `StringBuilder` to make this marginally faster, but it's more important to get a **correct** answer than a **fast** one.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  System.out.print(list[i]);
  if (i % 8 == 7) {
    System.out.println();
  } else {
    System.out.print(" ");
  }
}
if (size % 8 != 0) {
  System.out.println();
}
```

Technically, `print("\n")` and `println()` do not necessarily have the same effect, which is why the above doesn't just do `System.out.print((i % 8 ==7) ? "\n" : " ")`.

The extra if is to ensure that the last line is terminated even if it has fewer than 8 elements.

Answer (score 1):

To use Guava... Lists.partition breaks a list into a list of lists with a max length.

```
List<String> myList;
for (List<String> subs : Lists.partition(myList, 8)){
   System.out.println(Joiner.on(" ").join(subs));
}
```

[Lists.partition](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if ((i % 8 == 0) && (i > 0))
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    System.out.println(list[i] + "\n");
}
```

\n is for new line.

Comment: I dont want to put each one on one line.  I want to print 8 on each line

Comment: Then @MДΓΓ БДLL gave the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int nI = 0; nI < list.size(); nI++)
{
  System.out.print(list[nI] + " ");

  // new line if you hit 8th, 16th, etc. item in the list
  if (nI > 1 && ((nI+1) % 8 == 0))
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: This one also has a bug. It doesn't break on the correct elements.